# Amazon DynamoDB Java SDK won't use proxy settings

Tags: coldfusion, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, coldfusion-11

I'm trying to implement an interface to AWS' DynamoDB in ColdFusion 11, on a corporate network with an NTLM proxy. I started with BDCraven's [cfdynamo](https://github.com/bdcravens/cfdynamo) implementation, and extended it as per the [SDK docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html) to include my proxy settings.

Component structure and init function below. `getProxyParameters.cfm` pulls my proxy settings from the database and initialises `strProxyServer`, `strProxyPort` etc. These proxy settings and credentials have been tested in other ColdFusion code (using `cfhttp`) and are definitely valid.

```
component accessors="true" alias="cfc.DynamoClient" displayname="DynamoClient" hint="I handle interactions with an Amazon DynamoDB instance"{
    property name="aws_key" type="string" hint="The AWS Key";
    property name="aws_secret" type="string" hint="The AWS Secret";
    property name="aws_creds" type="object";
    property name="aws_dynamodb" type="object";

    include "/getProxyParameters.cfm";

    variables.aws_key = "";
    variables.aws_secret = "";

    public cfc.DynamoClient function init(required string aws_key, required string aws_secret){
        variables.aws_key = trim(arguments.aws_key);
        variables.aws_secret = trim(arguments.aws_secret);
        variables.aws_creds =  createObject("java","com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials").init(variables.aws_key, variables.aws_secret);
        aws_clientconfig = createObject("java","com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration").init();

        aws_clientconfig.setProtocol(createObject("java","com.amazonaws.Protocol").HTTPS);
        aws_clientconfig.setProxyHost(strProxyServer);
        aws_clientconfig.setProxyPort(strProxyPort);
        aws_clientconfig.setProxyUsername(strProxyUsername);
        aws_clientconfig.setProxyPassword(strProxyPassword);
        aws_clientconfig.setProxyDomain(strProxyDomain);

        variables.aws_dynamodb = createObject("java","com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBClient").init(aws_creds, aws_clientconfig);
        variables.aws_dynamodb.setEndpoint('dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com');
        variables.aws_dynamodb.setConfiguration(aws_clientconfig);

        return this;
    }

[...etc]
```

This `init` function returns without error, and `variables.aws_dynamodb` is an object of type `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBClient`.

The problem is that when I try to use it, the proxy settings are ignored:

```
public array function list_tables(string start_table, numeric limit=1){
    var table_request = createObject("java","com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.model.ListTablesRequest").init();  
    table_request.setLimit(arguments.limit);
    if(structKeyExists(arguments,"start_table")){
        table_request.setExcusiveStartTableName(trim(arguments.start_table));
    }
    return variables.aws_dynamodb.listTables(table_request).getTableNames();
}
```

This `list_tables` function waits for a long time, and then returns a ColdFusion error:
[image]

I've tried running `netstat -a` on the server while this request is happening, and the only connection is this SYN_SENT:

[image]

...and that IP looks like one of AWS's servers, not my proxy. Am I missing something obvious? Has anyone gotten this combination of tech to work properly?

Comment: Have you tried using the current AWS Java SDK to connect to Dynamo? The GitHub repo you reference hasn't been updated in 4 years and AWS completely revamped the DynamoDB API about two years ago, dropping support for many methods in the original API. I have a very simple example of working with the newer DynamoDB API in this GitHub repo: https://github.com/brianklaas/cfsummit2015  There's no example of setting up proxy settings, but it may worthwhile to try out the newer, supported API.

Comment: Thanks @Brian - I thought I was (d/led 1.10.45 to replace BDCraven's 1.3.xx) but got lost in Classpath Hell. It looks like `dynamodbv2` does indeed honour the proxy settings - if you would like to scribble an answer to that effect I'll drop in some working code.